# phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility not working

Tags: pear, php-7, phpcs

I've followed all the steps from the official git page for installing and configure PHPCompatibility for checking the compatibility of my code with PHP7 as described bellow:

1. Installation of `PHP_CodeSniffer` using pear.
2. Download and extraction of the most recent release (PHP 7.1 Sniffs - update 2016-12-14) on https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility/releases to directory `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/lib/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PHPCompatibility/`

After that I additionally did the following commands on terminal

3. Add PHPCompatibility to the standards

   `$ phpcs --config-set installed_paths /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/lib/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PHPCompatibility/`
4. Test if the PHPCompatibility was added as a standard

   `$ phpcs -i`

my output is:

> The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PHPCompatibility, PHPCS, PSR1, PSR2, Squiz and Zend

5. Set testVersion to PHP 7

   `$ phpcs --runtime-set testVersion 7.0 test.php` which correctly prints a report for test.php

But When I try to set PHPCompatibility as a standard anything happens and the terminal jumps to a new line for typing the next command.

```
`$ phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility test.php`
`Natalis-MacBook-Air:bin natalisilverio$ `
```

Could anyone advise what I am missing or doing wrong while trying to set PHPCompatibility as my standard? I tested phpcs --standard=Zend and it works correctly.

I am running MAMP 4.0.6 set to PHP 7.0.12
Thank you very much

Comment: Please, the original post was unreadable. Try to format better your questions and answers next time.

Comment: I was doing this now @MarcosPérezGude, thanks for your collaboration anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry because I can't help you with this question. But you'll get answers soon I wish.

Comment: The `--runtime-set` arg sets the testVersion value for that single run only, so you'll need to specify that each time. Or you can use `phpcs --config-set testVersion 7.0` to set it for all future runs.

Comment: Can you use composer? What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Can you show the contents of `test.php`, I suspect it doesn't have anything wrong with it according to the standard. Try using a class with the old style constructor or using a deprecated function like the old mysql functions

Answer (score -1):

Try running with `-p`. This will show the progress of the run.

Rather than showing nothing for a good result, it will show something like this:

```
.....SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS........................  60 / 181 (33%)
.S.......................................................... 120 / 181 (66%)
....................................S......S.S.............. 180 / 181 (99%)
.                                                            181 / 181 (100%)
```